# 301 Redirect between Wordpress & Hubspot

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301, hubspot

I have a WordPress website and landing pages on HubSpot. The problem is that my landing pages on HubSpot are under a subdomain, and if I use that in Google AdWords the subdomain appears in the ads, and I don't want that. I want the domain name to appear in Google ads, not the subdomain. So what I did is I created 301 redirects from Wordpress to Hubspot and it is working fine, however, I am losing the UTM parameters when the redirect happens.

Can someone suggest a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this can help you?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} an-old-url$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /a-new-url/? [R=301,L]
```

Untested, however, adding this to your htaccess file *should* carry across the UTM for you.

Comment: I don't think that would work. 

Here is what I am looking for:
Original URL: example.com/whatever/?utm_source=adwords&utm_campaign=ecom&utm_medium=cpc 

I want it to go to: subdomain.example.com/blablah/?utm_source=adwords&utm_campaign=ecom&utm_medium=cpc